# Install Ubuntu without taking over 2 hard drives?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ubuntu-10.04, hard-drive

I have 2 hard drives and when I do an auto install.. Ubuntu decides to take both hard drives... how do I prevent this from happening without my intervention?

Comment: @sarnold, he's doing an automatic installation.  The question explicitly says he wants to avoid manual "intervention."

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen, thanks, I completely overlooked the "without my intervention". Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Manually Create/modify the partition that you are installing ubuntu on.  Here is a tutorial that should help with the basics. http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2010/10/12/ubuntu-10-10-manual-disk-partitioning-guide/

Modified answer

Comment: The question clearly says he's doing an "auto install."

Comment: Yes I have manually done it - no problem... but let's say I want Ubuntu to do it on its own... Is there something I should be doing with my Hard drives to prevent this? Should my main hard drive be a master or 2nd be slave? I never checked it - but it works when I manually install. @dm03514

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use a [preseeding file](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-contents.html#preseed-partman).  The line should be something like:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
```

As the linked documentation warns, be very sure of which disk is `/dev/sda` (or whatever you choose).